# Trying to understand specific python keywords. Need help finding documentation

Tags: python

I'm learning python and I've stumbled upon certain keywords that just exist naturally inside of python. I have no idea what they're called and I'm looking for documentation on them so I can learn more.

I've googled all sorts of things involving keywords and built-in things in python but they all lead to different rabbit holes then the ones I'm looking for.

```
baseInput = input('>')
myWords = baseInput.split(' ')
for word in myWords:
    #do something
```

in the 'for' loop word just exists. It's something python does that seems similar to 'ch' that I've seen in tutorials or 'row' that I've seen in other when working with matrices. Do these have a name? Any way for me to find documentation on these keywords and learn more?

Comment: It's not a keyword. It's just a variable.

Comment: Are you referring to 'word' in this case? If so, it's similar to i, j, k, and row/col/etc. It's a way to create a temporary variable as you iterate over the for loop that has a name that is either useful for understanding what is being kept in the variable, or is standardized based off of convention.

Comment: 'word' is the `target_list` as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) and is user defined (so you can call it what ever you want) in that `for` statement to receive the individual looped objects. It is a spiffy feature of the `for` command to allow this dynamic variable creation.

Answer (score 1):

So here's the official Python documentation of the `for` statement:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement

```py
for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
              ["else" ":" suite]
```

In plain English, you have your 'target', which is just something that you declare--it could be 'word', 'row', or whatever variable name you find to be most appropriate to the context of your `for` loop.  The 'expression_list' is just the list or sequence that contains the objects over which you want to iterate.  They call it '*expression*_list' because it could be an expression instead of a plain list.  For example, if you were interested in the keys of a `dict`, you might do something like `for some_key in my_dict.keys():`.

The 'suite' is just whatever operations you want to perform on the objects specified by the target and sequence expressions that follow the `for` keyword.  A simple example could be:

```py
for some_key in my_dict.keys():
    print(some_key)
```

One thing to keep in mind is that `some_key` is just a variable you are declaring for the scope of the `for` statement, it won't be available any longer after the loop is finished.

Comment: Thank you so much. That last tidbit is what really helped about how it's just a variable in the scope of the for statement. In my head I thought it was something special in python.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to revisit the fundamentals of programming in general. You mention 'ch' and 'row', where you thought they were keywords. Like the others have said, they're just variables. You can follow the links to built in types and for loops but I'd go back to where you saw 'ch' and try to really understand that first and then apply the same knowledge to the snip of code in question. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

the 'word' in statement 'for word in myWords:' is not a keyword, its a variable.
User defined to be more clear.
You can use any variable at that place.

Say for example:

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for x in fruits:
  print(x)
```

here instead of x you can use any thing, like your name

```
fruits = ["apple", "banana", "cherry"]
for jacob in fruits:
  print(jacob)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, these are not python keywords. If I do something like this:

```
items = [64, 120, "Bob"]

for item in items:
    print(item)
```

Output:

```
64
120
Bob
```

"item" is not a keyword. This python for loop syntax allows us to do several things all on one line:

1. create a new variable named "item"
2. For each iteration of the loop (there are three iterations because
   the list has three items), our variable "item" takes on a new value
   (it is bound to the current value in the list). This means that
   during the first iteration, "item" is bound to 64. In the second
   iteration "item" is bound to 120. In the third iteration "item" is
   bound to the string "Bob".

I could have picked any name for my variable. It makes no difference:

```
items = [64, 120, "Bob"]

for hewfuewhfihu in items:
    print(hewfuewhfihu)
```

Output:

```
64
120
Bob
```

Answer (score 0):

**Learn about them [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)**

By the way these things are called iterations, they are not built in keyword of python.